# Swagger Endpoint not working on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, swagger, asp.net-core-3.1

I created an ASP.NET Core Web API using .NET Core 3.1 and added Swashbuckle Nuget packages to get the Swagger endpoint working. When I run the API locally, the Swagger endpoint works.
Then I deployed the API using AWS Lambda but the issue is the Swagger endpoint doesn't work there. This is the error I get:
[image: Swagger not working on AWS Lambda]

Is there a way I can get it working on this Lambda?

Comment: Just try to refresh the swagger page. Sometimes it happens when you have ambiguous HTTP methods.

Comment: For more detailed answer, please share your swagger configuration

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but I've recently stumbled upon a similiar problem.
When you deploy to AWS Lambda, it generates your endpoint with the `/Prod` stage, while your default Swagger UI initialization looks like `u.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Api")` (notice the lack of /Prod at the start). You just have to adjust your UI endpoint so it contains the /Prod stage, so a working solution would look like `u.SwaggerEndpoint("/Prod/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Api")`

Comment: This is the best answer I have come across.